# I can't upgrade Kubuntu 14.04 to 14.10

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kubuntu

I have issues upgrading Kubuntu 14.04 to 14.10, I looked up all the previous questions concerning this issue, but nothing helped. The problem I get is the same, either I try to update using command line or the Muon Update manager. Here the screen-shots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**And Here is the content of the Bug report, in case it highlights what's wrong:**

[image: Bug Report 1]

[image: Bug Report 2]

[image: Bug Report 3]

And here's the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
#############################################################
################### OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS ###################
#############################################################

###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty restricted universe multiverse

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

output of `apt-cache policy ubuntu-minimal`

```
ubuntu-minimal: Installed: 1.325 Candidate: 1.325 Version table: *** 1.325 0 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and when I attempted to report a bug with "ubuntu-bug" it crashes as well with `  QTreeWidgetItem(QTreeWidgetItem): too many arguments`

Comment: please post the output of `apt-cache policy ubuntu-minimal`

Comment: `ubuntu-minimal:
  Installed: 1.325
  Candidate: 1.325
  Version table:
 *** 1.325 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`

Comment: Do you have any PPA installed? What is the output of: `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`? Finally, does `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` returns OK?

Comment: I'd try dropping `fr.` from sources list, and trying to download from another mirror. Like this: `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse`

Comment: please post the output of `apt-cache policy ubuntu-minimal`

Comment: @A.B. I already did.

Comment: @PaulTomblin I see only the output of `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: @PaulTomblin ah, I see. It's a comment.

Comment: @Anton I'm not the original poster, but I'm having the same problem. And I tried switching to "Main server" from "U.S. Server". Same problem. My /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log is here: https://copy.com/gRNnB0PV3r3RrCIp

Comment: @PaulTomblin I'd try standard stuff like `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get clean`

Comment: Yeah, I tried those already. They didn't do anything.

Comment: Please post the content of `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90proxy`

Comment: No such file - I'm not behind a proxy.

Comment: Is `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` empty?

Comment: Only thing there is google-chrome.list. I tried removing it, and it didn't help. Check out the apt.log link in my comment above. It looks like the problem might be in xserver-xorg and/or PostGIS.

Comment: That is very weird: Your `trusty` channel does not have `main`: `deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty restricted universe multiverse`. @PaulTomblin I think you have offered a bounty on a problem whose origin might be elsewhere. You have effectively hijacked  a question.

Comment: Yes, I offered a bounty because I thought it was the same question. Now I'm pretty sure my problem is something to do with PostGIS and PostgreSQL and the way there is a removal blacklist on postgresql-* which is interfering with removing postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the GUI, you can use `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. I recommend that you use the US sources or Main server sources in your software settings.

You can open a terminal by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard.

Comment: I tried it using Muon Updater and using `do-release-upgrade`. Same results both ways.

Comment: Did you switch the sources from the software settings to the Main Ubuntu Server or the US Server?

Comment: I tried both. Same result. I also tried turning off every source except main and universe.

Comment: Backup your files first    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bit-team/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install backintime-gnome

Comment: This will make a backintime to the most stable operating system state, then you can do update and dist-upgrade again.

Comment: I'm using Kubuntu. I'm not sure installing a gnome program is a good idea.

Comment: @MostafaA.Hamid since when does `dist-upgrade` command do release upgrade?

Comment: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: That doesn't do a release upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to upgrade my Kubuntu desktop. But I discovered that there is a log file in /var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log which gives more information on what the problem was. In my case, it says "

```
2015-04-20 16:53:19,408 DEBUG blacklist expr '^postgresql-.*[0-9]\.[0-9].*' matches 'postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1'
2015-04-20 16:53:19,408 DEBUG The package 'postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1' is marked for removal but it's in the removal blacklist
2015-04-20 16:53:19,440 ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'The package 'postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1' is marked for removal but it is in the removal blacklist.'
2015-04-20 16:53:19,445 DEBUG abort called
```

Which means the problem is that postGIS is interfering with the way PostgreSQL never removes the old version and just installs the new one in parallel. The OP probably has a different problem, but that log file might be useful to discover what the problem is.